# onLocationChanged never gets called Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, location

```
package com.ecsmon.android.core;

import static com.ecsmon.android.constants.Constants.log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class GPSManager {

    private double currentLatitude = 0d;
    private double currentLongitude = 0d;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private Location lastLocationBestProvider = null;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private GPSListenerImpl mGPSListener;
    private com.ecsmon.android.core.LocationListener mOutListener;
    private boolean enabled = false;
    private GPSListenerImpl mNETListener;

    public GPSManager(Context ctx, com.ecsmon.android.core.LocationListener locationListener) {
    mCtx = ctx;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mOutListener = locationListener;
    }

    /**
     * Start location updates
     */
    public void start() {
    log("#### Started tracking");
    lastLocationBestProvider = getLastLocationFromBestProvider();
    if (lastLocationBestProvider != null) {
        currentLatitude = lastLocationBestProvider.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = lastLocationBestProvider.getLongitude();
        log("lat" + currentLatitude + " long " + currentLongitude);
    } else {
        log("last loaction is null");
    }
//  mGPSListener = new GPSListenerImpl("GPS");
    mNETListener = new GPSListenerImpl("NET");

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 1, mNETListener);
//  mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, mGPSListener);

    }

    private class GPSListenerImpl implements LocationListener {
    private String name = "";
    public GPSListenerImpl(String name) {
        log("listener created" + name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        log("######### LOCATION CHANGED CALLED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ##############");
        if (loc != null) {
        log("######### location changed " + loc.getAccuracy());
        currentLatitude = loc.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = loc.getLongitude();
        mOutListener.update(currentLongitude, currentLatitude);
        } else {
        log("location is null");
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        log("provider disabled > " + name);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        log("provider enabled > " + name);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        log("status changed");
    }
    }

    /**
     * Return last location saved in phone or null
     * 
     * @return Location
     */
    public Location getLastLocationFromBestProvider() {
    if (!enabled) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        String strLocationProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(strLocationProvider);
        if (location != null) {
        return location;
        }
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Returns human readable address from longitude and latitude
     * 
     * @param latitude
     * @param longitude
     * @return
     */
    public String getAddress(Double latitude, Double longitude) {
    if (!enabled) {
        return null;
    }
    String m = "";
    try {
        if (!Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        return null;
        }
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(mCtx);
        List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
        } else {
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            m = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ", "
                + addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        }
        }
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        log("No connection.");
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log("Can't read adress from this cordinates : lat = " + latitude + " long " + longitude); //
        return null;
    }
    return m;
    }

    /**
     * Removes all location updates
     */
    public void stop() {
    try {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mGPSListener);
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mNETListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    }

}
```

This is my main class for fetching current location and onLocationChanged never gets called. Im testing on emulator, and sending mock longitude and latitude via Emulator Control. Please Help this is driving me mad :(

Comment: Did you grant the permission to receive mock location in the manifest?

Comment: At first i didnt, but now after adding i ve noticed that emulator crashes after sending mock location

Comment: What does the stack trace from this crash say?

Answer (score 4):

Stefan was right. You need to do 2 things.

1. Grant access to mock location. As of now this needs to be specified in a special manifest file under src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml. Create that xml and add this permission to it:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"

2. Make sure your location manager is hooked on to the GPS provider and not the network provider. That information can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData

Answer (score 1):

You can change the GPS location values of emulator using `Emulator control`. By doing this (`onLocationChanged` method will work) you can test your application in Emulator

Comment: tried many times not woking but i solved it by using real device

Comment: But i checked using loading a kml file in Emulator control, and it works:) may i know which IDE your using?

Comment: hence u can test it in emulator. Are u able to see emulator control and GPS informations there

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on emulator it wont work, but on real device it found my location in sec

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was for the update frecuency of the accelerometer and magnetic_field sensors. Only changed "SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST" or SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME" to "SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL" and it´s worked correctly.
Curiously, the frecuency of the GPS sensor can be "SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST" and don´t have any problem.